# Can one say "with application to" instead of "with applications to" if only one application is intended?

Tags: prepositions, grammatical-number

I am writing a scientific article in which I am presenting a certain scientific approach. In this article, I highlight a (i.e. one) specific application of this approach. In my title, I'd thus like to say

> An approach to ..., with application to ....

However, using the singular "application" in the expression "with application to" feels weird to me. Is this phrasing correct or should I rephrase the sentence altogether? I've seen it used in other scientific article's titles by Googling "with application to", but maybe that's just because I'm looking for it literally.

EDIT: The entire title of the article *as is* reads: "A Generalized Approach to Operational, Globally Optimal Aircraft Mission Performance Evaluation, with Application to Direct Lift Control"

Comment: You used "a specific application *of* this approach."  Will that not work for your title?  Please provide more context, and feel free to take a [tour] of the site.

Comment: "With application to" may or may not be correct; it may be better to say "with application in" or "for" or "on". Without the **whole** sentence it's impossible to say, and any answers which offer an opinion do so without complete information.

Comment: I left out the other bits of the title because I reckoned it probably wouldn't make sense for most people, but for the sake of completeness I'll include it in an edit.

Comment: A Generalized Approach to Operational, Globally Optimal Aircraft Mission Performance Evaluation, having Application to Direct Lift Control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"With application to" is correct ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=15&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&content=with+application+to&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwith%20application%20to%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwith%20application%20to%3B%2Cc0)). What you can use in a title you can use as well in a paragraph.

Since there is but one application why not just write "with an application to"? Would that feel weird?

Comment: If the article is focussed on the approach in terms of its specific application you could also entitle it "An approach to X as applied to Y"

Answer (score 0):

Your original question is clear, stating the bare bones of the issue, which is commonplace in scientific and mathematical writing. The full quotation is helpful in confirming this clarity.

To use “with application to ... “reads clearly and unambiguously. Such constructs are common in scientific writing. If you were to use “... an application ...”, it would suggest (slightly) a focus on one specific area.

Answer (score 0):

The distinction between **application** and "**applications**" is that "**application**" is an uncountable noun in that context and thus expresses general applicability.

**Applications** is the unmodified plural of "an application" and the reader will expect suggestions for applications.